# How to recover a quciktime screen recording if you run out of storage while recording?

Tags: audio, video, screen-capture, quicktime, alias

I just recorded a few hours worth of footage on QuickTime. At one point, the recording automatically stopped because I ran out of space. I deleted a few files, and made some room.

After restarting the recording, and continuing where I left off, I have the final file I recorded. But that first file that was cut short from lack of storage seems to be missing.

I found the alias files, but they, "can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found."

Is there any way to recover the file?

Comment: If it stopped recording, there’s nothing to recover.  It’s like a cassette tape coming to an end the  song on the radio might still be playing but no recording is made

Comment: @Allan Those were the days!